# How to call/get service function by function name in directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, service, ionic-framework, directive

I want to reuse some pattern in directive like modal poped with a list of data. In the modal there will be a method to get data and the method is defined in a service. The service is dynamically generated through the parameter passed from view. But I do not know how to get the service function and call it in the directive(not in the testCtrl). 
Here is a sample code:

```
 angular.module('app',[ionic]).controller('testCtrl', function(customerService, productService){
                         //some controller function
                });

     angular.module('app').factory('customerService',function(){
            return{
                    getCustomers:fuction(){...}
                  }
     });

     angular.module('app').factory('productService',function(){
            return{
                    getProducts:function(){...}
                  }
     });    



angular.module('app').directive('chooseModal',function(){
              var linkFunc = function (scope, ele, attrs) {

          /**This gets the service instance**/
          var service = ele.injector().get(scope.serviceName);

          scope.getData = function(){

            //How to call the service function like getCustomers/getProducts here(the function name can be got through the scope.serviceMethod)?

          }
         }

         return {
           restrict: 'EA',
           scope: {
                    templateUrl: "@templateUrl",
                    serviceName: '@',
                    serviceMethod:'@'
                   },
           link: linkFunc
         };
})
```

And the view is defined like this:

```
  <input type="text" template-url="XXX" service-name="customerService" service-method="getCustomers" choose-modal>
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE QUESTION:**
I have tried the solution proposed by Pankaj and I found out that the service function looks like this:
[image]. 
**Why does this look like an anonymous function?**

Well actually, the service function that I would like to use is more like passing the function as a parameter(like below) :

service.getData(serviceFunction,currentPage,currentPageSize,xxxx).success(function(){....})

and the serviceFunction will be called inside the service.getData, like this:
[image]

But with the 'Anonymous function'(Sorry I don't know if I called this right), this will not work. Can anyone please elaborate a little bit more? I am totally confused why this would not work in directive.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having `element.injector()` you should use `$injector` for getting instance of `service` for resolving dependency from module.

As you are passing `serviceName` & `serviceMethod` using `@`(one-way) binding, you should use pass value in `{{}}` interpolation.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" template-url="XXX" 
  service-name="{{'customerService'}}" 
  service-method="{{'getCustomers'}}" choose-modal>
```

**Code**

```
/**This gets the service instance**/
var service = $injector.get(scope.serviceName);

scope.getData = function() {
  //this would call service method.
  service[scope.serviceMethod]();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. Since I am quite new to AngularJS, could you please explain a little bit more about why I should use {{}} interpolation here and why service[XX] can get the service function? And please see the update, I found out that under this circumstance, service[attrs.serviceMethod] will not work. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. With service[scope.serviceMethod] this will work. Spotted, we should use service[scope.serviceMethod] instead of service[scope.serviceMethod](). Do you know why I can reach the service return function(the service is defined by factory) by using '[]' ?